# The 100 game - CanIWin()

Tags: java, algorithm, game-theory

**Problem:**

1. Two players pick numbers from a common pool of number to reach a combined total.
2. The player who get to reach/cross the target value wins.
3. The problem is to find out if player-1 can enforce a strategy to win - for a given total and a pool of numbers.

**My Approach:**

Assuming both the players pick the optimal number from the available pool.
By optimal, I mean -

1. Check if the highest number available in the pool >= remaining value. [yes]=> return the highest value available.
2. If winning is not possible, pick the highest available number (`RequiredToWin - HighestNumberInThePool`) in the pool that will NOT guarantee a win in the next turn.

I just came up with 'a' solution and wrote the code. I am trying to analyze if it is rite? optimal, in terms of time, space. Also trying to understand how I can improve my coding conventions - Global variables and the way I am using the conditional statements. Is this solution rite ?

In the example - I used the expected sum from 100 to 105 -- to show the optimal pick in the output. See Player-1 picks 5 from the available pool [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

***Edit*** This is not the solution to the problem. This approach fails for the case {pool:[1-5], Total:12}. The function says, Player-2 always wins, But Player-1 can always win, if he starts with a 3.

```
/* In "the 100 game," two players take turns adding, to a running 
total, any integer from 1..10. The player who first causes the running 
total to reach or exceed 100 wins. 
What if we change the game so that players cannot re-use integers? 
For example, if two players might take turns drawing from a common pool of numbers 
of 1..15 without replacement until they reach a total >= 100. This problem is 
to write a program that determines which player would win with ideal play. 

Write a procedure, "Boolean canIWin(int maxChoosableInteger, int desiredTotal)", 
which returns true if the first player to move can force a win with optimal play. 

Your priority should be programmer efficiency; don't focus on minimizing 
either space or time complexity. 
*/

    package Puzzles;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class The100Game{
        List<Integer> pool;
        int raceTo;

        The100Game(int poolMax, int finalSum){
            /*  If (finalSum > combined sum of all numbers). 
             *  This is an impossible problem to solve  
             */
            if(finalSum > ((poolMax*poolMax + poolMax)/2)){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected sum cannot be achieved!");
            }

            raceTo = finalSum;
            pool = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=0;i<poolMax;i++)
                pool.add(i+1);
        }

        /*  Autoplay the game with optimal mooves   */
        boolean canIWin(){
            int turns = 0;
            while(raceTo>0){
                turns++;
                System.out.println("Player"+( (turns%2==0)?"2":"1" )+" ==> "+pickANumber()+"   == Remaining ["+raceTo+"]");
            }
            return (turns%2==1);
        }

        /*  Pick an Optimal number, so to win 
         *  or prevent he opponent from winning 
         */
        int pickANumber(){
            int leastMax = -1;
            int len = pool.size();
            for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
                int tmp = pool.get(i);
                if(tmp>=raceTo){
                    /*  Winning Pick */
                    pool.remove(i);
                    raceTo -= tmp;
                    return tmp; 
                }else{
                    if(leastMax > 0){
                        /*  Picking the highest number available in the pool might let the next player win. 
                         *  So picking a number < leastMax, if available - to gaurentee otherwise.  */
                        if(tmp < leastMax){
                            pool.remove(i);
                            raceTo -= tmp;
                            return tmp;
                        }else{
                            continue;
                        }
                    }   

                    if(i-1 >= 0) {
                        /*  We know, the highest number available in the pool is < raceTo (target sum)
                         *  Check in the pool 
                         *  if the sum of the highest number + nextHighest number >=  raceTo (target sum)
                         *      [True]  => Skip both the numbers and look for a number < the LeastMax 
                         *                   so the opposite player does not win.
                         *      [False] => The highest number in the pool is the best pick
                         */
                        if(tmp+pool.get(i-1) < raceTo){
                            pool.remove(i);
                            raceTo -= tmp;
                            return tmp;
                        }else{
                            leastMax = raceTo - tmp;
                            i--;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }else{
                        pool.remove(i);
                        raceTo -= tmp;
                        return tmp;
                    }
                }
            }

            /*  The raceTo sum cannot be achieved in this turn.
             *  There is no number available in the pool 
             *  that can prevent a Win in the next turn. 
             *  So we return the highest number availble in the pool.
             */
            int tmp = pool.get(pool.size()-1);
            pool.remove(pool.size()-1);
            raceTo -= tmp;
            return tmp;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            The100Game game = new The100Game(15, 105);
            System.out.println("\nPlayer-"+(game.canIWin()?"1":"2")+" wins!");
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ```java
> --------------------------------------
> Player1 ==> 15   == Remaining [90]
> Player2 ==> 14   == Remaining [76]
> Player1 ==> 13   == Remaining [63]
> Player2 ==> 12   == Remaining [51]
> Player1 ==> 11   == Remaining [40]
> Player2 ==> 10   == Remaining [30]
> Player1 ==> 9   == Remaining [21]
> Player2 ==> 8   == Remaining [13]
> Player1 ==> 5   == Remaining [8]
> Player2 ==> 7   == Remaining [1]
> Player1 ==> 6   == Remaining [-5]
>
> Player-1 wins!
> ```

Comment: Is your question just if the algorithm you have used is the optimal algorithm?

Comment: @mdewitt I tried evaluating all the cases I could think of. Is this solution rite ? and is there any other optimal way ?

Comment: Without the restriction on not reusing numbers, can't you always win by going first and saying "1"?

Comment: Yeah, without that restriction of "no re-use", for a total of 100 with an pool of numbers from [1-15], I guess you can win it in 6 turns max (15x6=90)...

Comment: This is not the optimal strategy. By the way, what kind of numbers would be in the pool? For instance, are they always consecutive? EDIT: Wait, I assumed you could re-use the numbers.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's a guaranteed win to go first with a pool from 1 to 15 if going to 100. My comment was unclear, but I was using a pool from 1 to 10 and going to 100, per the first sentence in the code comments that explained the game.

Comment: because if the the no repetition restriction, the [1-10] pool will only make up to a sum of 55. So No solution will be possible.

But with out that restriction, I am not sure.

Comment: Now that I think a little more... if the game uses consecutive integers from 1 to n, and the target score is a multiple of n, then the player who goes first should always win, assuming reuse.  If no reuse, then the target score must also be restricted or the game may have no end.

Comment: @splungebob If reuse, player 1 can then enforce a win whenever the target value is not a multiple of n+1, and player 2 can enforce a win if it is a multiple of n+1.

Comment: ... and where is the proof your "optimal" strategy is indeed optimal? That should probably be your first step, as there is no point in implementing that strategy otherwise.

Comment: The "no reuse" constraint is not clear from the problem definition. Without it, this is a classic problem, pretty easy to solve. Are you sure this constraint exists?

Comment: @meriton I only said, i came up with a solution. It is not Optimal. For example consider the case {Pool:[1-5], Total : 12}. My algorithm tells player-2 will win. But if the player 1 starts with 3, he can always win. I am trying to figure out, how to find the optimal solution (as per the problem statement, if a strategy exists that can ensure a win in all cases).

Comment: @PatriceGahide Yes. The "No Reuse" constraint applies to this problem, unlike the classic problem we know. The "no reuse" constraint implies both the players pick a number in for each turn from the common pool and the number and number once used cannot be re-used by either player.

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote. In any case, I tested your code, and player 2 wins when calling `new The100Game(7, 19);`. However, player 1 can guarantee a win if he starts with a 1, and then chooses 9 minus whatever his opponent chooses.

Comment: Oh, this question would probably belong to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). (Possible reason for the downvote)

Answer (score 1):

If numbers are positive integers and can be resused (and are in a consecutive range 1 to N), then your basic idea is essentially correct, picking the largest number possible that does not guarantee an opponent's win on the second to last move will make the total equal to N+1. Then no matter what the opponent does, you can win. So if the total target sum M is divisible by N+1, then player two can win, by keeping the sum always divisible by N+1, otherwise player 1 can win by first making the sum divisible by N+1 and stealing player 2's strategy. If numbers are not consecutive and/or cannot be reused, then the problem seems a lot harder.